# Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable when trying to rotate an image

Tags: flutter, async-await

I've created a basic example to simulate my issue, here is the code:

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:isolate';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Uint8List? foto;

  Future<Widget> loadImage() async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/IMG_4510.HEIC');

    foto = data.buffer.asUint8List();

    return Image.memory(foto!);
  }

  void _rotateIsolate(SendPort sendPort) {
    final ReceivePort receivePort = ReceivePort();

    sendPort.send(receivePort.sendPort);

    receivePort.listen((dynamic data) {
      if (data is Uint8List) {
        final rotatedImageBytes = _doRotate(data);

        sendPort.send(rotatedImageBytes);
      }
    });
  }

  Uint8List _doRotate(Uint8List foto) {
    img.Image image = img.decodeImage(foto)!;
    img.Image rotatedImage = img.copyRotate(image, angle: 90);

    return Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(rotatedImage));
  }

  Future<void> rotateImage() async {
    final receivePort = ReceivePort();

    await Isolate.spawn(_rotateIsolate, receivePort.sendPort);

    final completer = Completer<Uint8List>();

    receivePort.listen((message) {
      completer.complete(message);

      receivePort.close();
    });

    foto = await completer.future;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            FutureBuilder(
              future: loadImage(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  return snapshot.data as Widget;
                } else {
                  return const CircularProgressIndicator();
                }
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => rotateImage(),
              child: const Text('Rotate'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When I press the button `Rotate` flutter throws this exception:

```
Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message: object is unsendable - Library:'dart:async' Class: _AsyncCompleter@4048458 (see restrictions listed at `SendPort.send()` documentation for more information)
```

Which is weird, because I based my code off of [this guy's work](https://medium.com/@ahmedtahaelelemy/exploring-thread-implementation-isolates-in-flutter-for-better-performance-55a1569ffbb9), which downloads an image from the web, so I figured that rotating an image should've been almost the same thing.

I also tried some basic parallel computing, like calculating the fibonacci sequence, as described in [this medium post](https://santhosh-adiga-u.medium.com/multithreading-in-flutter-238aa63e29bd), but the EXACT same exception is thrown.

Now I don't know if I'm doing something wrong or there is some bug going on with the Flutter engine.

I'm on the latest (as of today) version of the stable channel of the Flutter engine:
`Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.8)`

Anyone has any idea on why this same exception is being thrown on different (and tested) scenarios?

PS: the local asset can be any image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR:** You can't pass a method of `_HomeState` as the callback function for the isolate (fix it by making the method a top-level function), but there are also some other problems with the states and widgets.

---

First of all, let's simplify the isolate job by using Flutter's [`compute`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html) function.

(Why? Because our main focus is to fix the `Illegal argument in isolate message` error, and using `compute` is preferred for simple isolation task anyway. See: [Using isolates](https://dart.dev/language/concurrency#using-isolates). Basically `Isolate.run` is preferred over `Isolate.spawn`, and `compute` is the Flutter's version of `Isolate.run`.)

Import `package:flutter/foundation.dart` and replace the `rotateImage` method to the following code:

```dart
Future<void> rotateImage() async {
  foto = await compute(_doRotate, foto!);
}
```

Now when clicking on the Rotate button, you will see the exact same error message. This happens because the callback function being sent, which is `_doRotate`, is a method of the `_HomeState` class. To fix it, move `_doRotate` outside the `_HomeState` class and make it a top-level function. After doing this, you have to stop the app and re-run it (hot restart won't work).

Now when you click Rotate, no errors shown but also nothing happens. This happens because:

1. The widget won't notice state changes if we only reassign the state like this: `foto = await compute(_doRotate, foto!);`
2. `FutureBuilder` will always take data from the returned value of `loadImage`, which is the original image from the assets.

To fix the first problem, we have to use `setState`:

```dart
Future<void> rotateImage() async {
  final rotatedFoto = await compute(_doRotate, foto!);
  setState(() {
    foto = rotatedFoto;
  });
}
```

To fix the second problem, we can just use a simple ternary operator to show the image instead of `FutureBuilder`:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    foto != null ? Image.memory(foto!) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () => rotateImage(),
      child: const Text('Rotate'),
    )
  ],
),
```

Lastly, we have to initialize the value for `foto`. Add these methods inside `_HomeState`:

```dart
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  initFoto();
}

Future<void> initFoto() async {
  final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/profile.png');
  setState(() {
    foto = data.buffer.asUint8List();
  });
}
```

Now it should work as expected, and we have successfully used separate isolate to rotate the image. We can remove `loadImage` and `_rotateIsolate` methods as they are not being used anymore.

---

**FULL CODE:**

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as img;

Uint8List _doRotate(Uint8List foto) {
  img.Image image = img.decodeImage(foto)!;
  img.Image rotatedImage = img.copyRotate(image, angle: 90);

  return Uint8List.fromList(img.encodePng(rotatedImage));
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Uint8List? foto;

  Future<void> rotateImage() async {
    final rotatedFoto = await compute(_doRotate, foto!);
    setState(() {
      foto = rotatedFoto;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initFoto();
  }

  Future<void> initFoto() async {
    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load('assets/images/IMG_4510.HEIC');

    setState(() {
      foto = data.buffer.asUint8List();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            foto != null ? Image.memory(foto!) : CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => rotateImage(),
              child: const Text('Rotate'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you so much for the very detailed explanation... that's some ChatGPT level of answer right there. Awesome. Now, while I did understand your explanation, I decided to test your code and I'm getting a `Null check operator used on a null value` exception when `img.Image image = img.decodeImage(foto)!;`. I tried debugging and it gets weirder, the variable foto is not null and contains the image, but for some reason it throws a null exception... any idea why?

Comment: No problem, it was fun trying to make the code works! If you see the implementation of [`decodeImage`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/decodeImage.html), it calls the [`findDecoderForData`](https://pub.dev/documentation/image/latest/image/findDecoderForData.html) function, which check for the image type. Seems like HEIC format is not there, so it returns null. I ran my code with a PNG asset so it works.

Comment: Yeah that was my understanding as well... I did also try with a jpg image and the same thing happened. I'll try with a png and post back the results.

Comment: There are separate decoders for each file type, maybe you can do a test to see if the decoder actually returns null for your asset, for example `final test = img.JpegDecoder().decode(foto)`

Comment: Yep, worked like a charm. Although the process is a little slow. But it works. Thanks again for the awesome explanation.

Comment: By the way, you should make a Medium post about this and explain it there, you did a much better job explaining than the other guys.